# fswatch with grep not piping

Tags: bash, fswatch

I want to use fswatch to run a file through my unit test framework whenever I save.

As a test, I run fswatch and make a minor change to /my/path/test.txt in my text editor and get the output I expected:

```
$ fswatch . | xargs -I {} echo {} {}
/my/path/test.txt /my/path/test.txt
```

But if I insert a grep in the middle and repeat the process I get no output:

```
$ fswatch . | grep test | xargs -I {} echo {} {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit*:

fswatch + grep works fine by itself

```
$ fswatch . | grep test
/my/path/test.txt
```

Comment: `-0` is for `NULL` de-limiting,  the [official-page](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) says, use `fswatch -o path` ? Is the result the same?

Comment: `fswatch -o . | xargs -I {} echo {} {}` then I get `1 1` as output every time I save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, `--line-buffered` tells `grep` *not* to block-buffer output, hence writing entire lines immediately to standard output.  Block-buffering is the default behaviour when `grep` is writing to a pipe, line-buffering is the default when it's writing to a terminal.

Now: as explained in `fswatch` documentation, file names *can* contain new line characters.  Hence the existence of `-0` (as other file-handling utilities such as `find` have).  If you tell `grep` to line-buffer *and* you hit such a file you will end up with a *corrupt* `fswatch` record.

Why aren't you filtering using filters instead?  For simple filtering they're easy to use.  That way `fswatch` will internally match file names without your having to worry about these peculiarities and corner-cases.

Answer (score 2):

man grep:

```
   --line-buffered
          Use line buffering on output.   This  can  cause  a  performance
          penalty.
```

When using grep as last pipe command then linebuffered is the deault.

Comment: Good idea; it seems almost better than the native `fswatch` options (`--include`, `--exclude`), although I really can't say for sure... +1

Comment: As I explained, it's not "better", unless you're sure about the characters contained in all the file names that will be output by `fswatch`.  Assuming you don't have this kind of control, you should not line buffer light-heartedly, otherwise you may very well hit all the issues that are taken care of by filters and `fswatch` option `-0`.